# BadMethodCallException: Method App\Http\Controllers\UserController::getAuthenticatedUser does not exist

Tags: laravel

When i try to Get the authenticated user data from API i get this error:
BadMethodCallException: Method App\Http\Controllers\UserController::getAuthenticatedUser does not exist. in file D:\OpenServer\OSPanel\domains\Pumpkin\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controller.php on line 68
Please help to fix it

My userController:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\PasswordReset;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use JWTAuth;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\SendsPasswordResetEmails;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function authenticate(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

        try {
            if (! $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
                return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 400);
            }
        } catch (JWTException $e) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'could_not_create_token'], 500);
        }

        return response()->json(compact('token'));
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        auth()->logout();
        return response()->json(['message'=>'Successfully logged out']);
    }
    protected function respondWithToken($token)
    {
        return response()->json([
            'access_token' => $token,
            'token_type' => 'bearer',
            'expires_in' => auth()->factory()->getTTL() * 60
        ]);
    }

    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);

        if($validator->fails()){
            return response()->json($validator->errors()->toJson(), 400);
        }

        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $request->get('name'),
            'email' => $request->get('email'),
            'password' => Hash::make($request->get('password')),
        ]);

        $token = JWTAuth::fromUser($user);

        return response()->json(compact('user','token'),201);
    }

    public function getAuthenticatedUser()
    {
        try {
            if (! $user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate()) {
                return response()->json(['user_not_found'], 404);
            }
        } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException $e) {

            return response()->json(['token_expired'], $e->getStatusCode());

        } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException $e) {

            return response()->json(['token_invalid'], $e->getStatusCode());

        } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException $e) {

            return response()->json(['token_absent'], $e->getStatusCode());
        }
        return response()->json(compact('user'));
    }
}
```

My api.php

```
Route::post('auth/register', 'UserController@register');
Route::post('auth/login', 'UserController@authenticate');
Route::post('auth/recover', 'UserController@recover');
Route::get('open', 'DataController@open');
Route::post('/password/email', 'ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail');
Route::post('/password/reset', 'ResetPasswordController@reset');
Route::group(['middleware' => ['jwt.verify']], function() {
    Route::get('user', 'UserController@getAuthenticatedUser');
    Route::get('closed', 'DataController@closed');
});
```

Middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use JWTAuth;
use Exception;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Http\Middleware\BaseMiddleware;

class JwtMiddleware extends BaseMiddleware
{

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        try {
            $user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            if ($e instanceof \Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException){
                return response()->json(['status' => 'Token is Invalid']);
            }else if ($e instanceof \Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException){
                return response()->json(['status' => 'Token is Expired']);
            }else{
                return response()->json(['status' => 'Authorization Token not found']);
            }
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: use `php artisan route:list` to check of the route exists.

Comment: @Makdous | GET|HEAD | api/user | | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@getAuthenticatedUser | api,jwt.verify | –

Comment: Check your project for accidental duplicate naming of `UserController` class (or other class in question) - maybe you've created a "dummy" controller based on this one and just forgot to change the class name => autoloader just chose one of those (it actually happened to me x) )

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide the full log output from \storage\logs?

Also, sending the router as a parameter to the function may help.

```php
Route::group([
    'middleware' => 'jwt.verify'
], function ($router) {
    Route::get('user', 'UserController@getAuthenticatedUser');
    Route::get('closed', 'DataController@closed');
});
```

Comment: @daniela-c-montenegro The parameter did not help [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_6-uH0s-DAUf5Zjjmb8di3Q5xx86uHUk/view?usp=sharing)